# Why can't I make a loop from -1 to 1 with 0.1 step?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to implement a loop from -1 to 1 with step 0.1. It should take around 21 step to complete. Like this:

```
(do ((i -1 (+ i 0.1)))
    ((= i 1) i)
  (display i))
```

But then I'm starting this code my compiler goes wild. There are much more then 21 step as I mentioned.

I also tried this one:

```
(do ((i -1.0 (+ i 0.1)))
    ((= i 1.0) i)
  (display i))
```

And end up with this:

```
(do ((i -1
        (string->number (~r (+ i 0.1) #:precision 1))
        ))
    ((= i 1) i)
  (display i))
```

I just wanted to do something like this in C++:

```
for (double x=-1; x<=1; x+=0.1) {
cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

This C++ code makes 21 step.

Comment: As Barmar said, this happens because floating point operations suffer from loss of precision. Anyway, you can improve your first solution a bit by changing the condition to `(>= i 1.0)`, so the loop ends.

Comment: Note that your C++ example would be just as wrong if you translated it correctly. The reason you see a difference is because you use `=` in racket but `>=` in C++.

Comment: The correct approach is to compute N from -10 to 10 (integer type) and interpolate the float with N / 10.0